# Is the first ten characters of a user in Active Directory GUID or SID enough to uniquely identify an account for a legacy app?

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I'm migrating an app from an old novell based authentication model to Active Directory.  The app reads the UniqueID from the existing authentication process and uses that unique ID to discern that the account is unique (becuase, in Novell, I think you can have duplicate users, as long as they are in different parts of the tree).

The issue is that becuase this app was written ten years ago, there are only 10 characters in the field that stores this unique ID.  So I can't store the entire GUID or SID.  I don't have control over the database either.

So, I was thinking about substringing out the first 10 characters and using this as a Unique ID instead.  While this is obviously not ideal, I can't think of any other way to get this unique ID.

Thoughts?

TL:DR : Is the first 10 characters of a AD Users SID/GUID "unique enough"?

EDIT: I'm not the least bit partial to anything in AD, like a SID or GUID exclusively. If there is anything that could be made to be less than 10 characters that would be unique enough that would work just fine.

Comment: I would say not to count on the first 10 chars being unique. A guid consists of  basically 16 bytes of data (128 bits) encoded as hexidecimal (base 16). The only thing I can think to do is to use a different encoding like base 64 of the original numeric value. First convert the guid into two `long` values and then encode those as base 64. Note I do not mean base64 encode the Guid.ToString() value. I mean express the values as base 64 instead of base 10 or base 16.

Comment: That sounds practical.  Could you post an answer that would show a quick mockup of something like that?

Comment: Actually, I don't think that would work because the max value of a `ulong` is 18446744073709551615 (base 10) which is `P//////////` (base 64) which is 12 characters. So that gets you a max of 24 characters instead of 32 but that's not good enough. Sorry. Even base 256 still gets you 16 characters total.

Comment: Thanks @GreatAndPowerfulOz.  Maybe I should post this in Code Golf instead ;) "What's the most unique ID I can get from AD with just ten characters"

Comment: If you operate with only one domain, you can take last part of user SID. SID consists of 2 parts: domain part and unique part generated by a domain controller on security principal creation